# ¿Como puedo solucionar este error en los diccionarios ? Traductor de palabras PYTHON

Tags: python, diccionarios

Quiero buscar dentro de un diccionario y que solo me traiga el valor de la clave introducida... Este es el error

> TypeError: must be str, not dict

```
import interface as In

 

words={"Emberracarse ": "furious" , "Perico ": "parakeet","Sapo":"informer","Tombo" :"pólice", "Lucas ": "money", "Rumbiar" : "to dance","Ñero" : "delinquent", "Gamín" : "rude",
"Culicagao" : "child","Bizcocho" : "gorgeous"," Choro" : "robber","Calletano" : "reserved","Desparche" : "bored" , 
"Bagre" : "catfish","Desechable": "homeless","Chiviado" : "cheap copy","Abeja" : "crafty","Traga" : "in love","Recochar" : "bother",
 "Recochar" : "Joking" ,"Necio" : "foolish","Mecato" : "Candys", "Líchigo" : "Vegetables and fruits", "Hostigante" : "harassing","Jartera" : "nuisance",
 "Enguayabado" : "hangover","Cantaleta": "scold","Bacano" : "Cool","Amañado" : "Customary","Pana" : "corudoy","Parcero": "Friend"}





def buscar_palabras(self,palabras):
   word=words
   print(In.recibir_string("¿Que palabra deseas buscar?"))
   for clave, valor in words.items():
       if clave.find(words) != valor:
          word=valor
   In.imprimir(word)
```

Comment: Hola. ¿Qué error sale cuando usas tu código? Por favor, **edita tu pregunta y añádelo**, tan completo como puedas. Como texto.

Comment: Ya agregue el error

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: `palabras` es un diccionario; `Palabras` es una clase y `ofrecer_saludos()` es un método de instancia, no de clase (o sea, `Palabras.ofrecer_saludos()` es ilegal. Además la función espera que le pases un diccionario ... No código no tiene ni pies ni cabeza; hay que hacerlo de nuevo.

Answer (score 0):

veo que has cometido el mismo error varias veces. Tomemos por ejemplo esta línea:

```py
            Palabras.ofrecer_saludos()
```

`Palabras` es una *clase*, no un *objeto* ya inicializado. En sí esto no es ilegal, pero debes agregar un argumento adicional, que normalmente es añadido por default: `self`. Una forma rápida de solucionar esto es inicializando la clase, algo así como `mis_palabras = Palabras(...)` (reemplazando `...` con los argumentos que definiste en `Palabras.__init__`), y así ya no necesitas poner `self` en el método. Luego, reemplaza las llamadas a `Palabras` por llamadas a su instancia, `mis_palabras`.

Aparte, olvidaste poner el argumento `saludos`. Este no es el mismo que el diccionario `saludos`... Si quieres usar el diccionario, quita el argumento `saludos` de la definición de `Palabras`. O puedes escribir `mis_palabras.ofrecer_saludos(saludos)`, si lo prefieres. Lo mismo aplica para todos los otros métodos que estás llamando.

---

Creo que todo este bloque:

```py
        if opcion == 1:
            Palabras.ofrecer_saludos()
        elif opcion == 2:
            Palabras.ofrecer_despedidas()
        elif opcion == 3:
            Cultura.buscar_frases()
        elif opcion == 4:
            Palabras.buscar_palabras()
        elif opcion == 5:
            Usuario.experiencia_usuario()
        elif opcion == 6:
            Palabras.agregar_palabras()
```

tiene el mismo error. Si sigues el consejo para `Palabras.ofrecer_saludos` (arriba) con todas las líneas que usen `Palabras`, `Usuario` y `Cultura` dentro del bloque que te señalo, tu problema debe estar resuelto.

Comment: Además pienso que estas referencias te pueden ayudar a entender mejor el concepto: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries y https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions.

Comment: @DebyJohanaLeonRodríguez, te damos la bienvenida a SO. Si está respuesta te ha sido útil, siéntete libre de marcarla como tu respuesta seleccionada ;)

Comment: Oh cielos, me has cambiado la jugada al editar todo el código de tu pregunta. Ahora la respuesta está bien desfasada :/